# how to hide console warning for proptype check in jest

Tags: jestjs

react component's proptype as below

```
comp2.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    }
```

In code i am using like this.

```
const MAP_TYPE_TO_URL = {};
// some values for MAP_TYPE_TO_URL : eg : MAP_TYPE_TO_URL['d'] = 'some value' , etc
// so i am manipulating MAP_TYPE_TO_URL with 'type' values
example:  


 if(MAP_TYPE_TO_URL[type] == 'somevalue'){
      // some code
    }
```

in code coverage, type is reported that it is not testing when null..or else part not called error

So to make the code coverage pass, i need to pass null or some other values which is not mentioned in propTypes of that component.eg:

```
var f = mount(<comp1 type="some-1" />)
```

everything is working fine as expected.

The problem: console warning appearing in jest console that proptype should have the value from the defined values of that component.

How to hide this error, please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you just fix it by passing a valid value there should not be a warning

e.g.:

```
var f = mount(<comp1 type="vitamin-b" />)
```

Comment: @sathishkumar probably you should write different test cases to cover all of your branches in the implementation

Comment: mount(<comp1 type="vitamin-b-some-wrong" />) when i use this line jest, console warns that it is a wrong value as per the proptype of comp1